# How can I get TalkBack to read the Android progressBar progress?

Tags: android-progressbar, talkback

I am trying to get TalkBack to read the progress on the progress bar without much luck. Any ideas on how I can get that information so that TalkBack can say it.

thx

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
Button btnStartProgress;
ProgressDialog progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();

private long fileSize = 0;

private String msgProgress ="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnStartProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartProgress);
    btnStartProgress.setOnClickListener(
             new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("File downloading ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        //reset progress bar status
        progressBarStatus = 0;

        //reset filesize
        fileSize = 0;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

              // process some tasks
              progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();


              // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              // Update the progress bar
              progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                  //progressBar.setMessage(msgProgress);

                }
              });
            }

            // ok, file is downloaded,
            if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // close the progress bar dialog
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
          }
           }).start();

           }

            });

    }

// file download simulator... a really simple
public int doSomeTasks() {

    while (fileSize <= 1000000) {

        fileSize++;

        if (fileSize == 250000) {
            //msgProgress = "25 Percent";
            return 25;
        } else if (fileSize == 500000) {
            //msgProgress = "50 Percent";
            return 50;
        } else if (fileSize == 750000) {
            //msgProgress = "75 Percent";
            return 75;
        } else if (fileSize == 900000) {
            //msgProgress = "90 Percent";
            return 90;
        }
        // ...add your own

    }

    return 100;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159749/global-tts-in-android) can create a a TTS Singleton and add a method that checks if the accessibility is enabled . call the the method say(message) everytime you show the progress bar.

This is how I implemented it

```
public class AccessibilityUtil implements OnInitListener {

private static final String TAG = AccessibilityUtil.class.getSimpleName();

private static final AccessibilityUtil instance = new AccessibilityUtil();
private String message;
private static TextToSpeech tts=null;

private static boolean isAccesibilityEnabled() {

     return ((AccessibilityManager) TmcPlusApplication.getInstance()
     .getSystemService(
     TmcPlusApplication.getInstance().ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE))
     .isEnabled();


}

public static AccessibilityUtil getInstance() {

    return instance;
}

public void say(String message) {

    if (isAccesibilityEnabled()) {
        if (tts == null) {
            this.message = message;
            tts = new TextToSpeech(<Your Application object>.getInstance(), (AccessibilityUtil) instance);
        } else {
            speakOut();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Text to speech enabled");
        speakOut();
    }

}

/*
 * utters the message String
 */
private void speakOut() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Text to speech the word "+message);
    tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

public void stopTTS() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.shutdown();
        tts.stop();
        tts = null;
    }
}
```

}

When u call the say() method , it looks something like this

```
AccessibilityUtil.getInstance().say("Loading. Please wait");
```

Hope it helps